# 新しいタグの許可の要望: playframework

Tags: 討議, 完了

[Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)用のタグ [playframework] を提案します。  
本家SOでも [playframework] は使用されています。 https://stackoverflow.com/tags/playframework

Comment: どの質問につけて欲しいですか？

Comment: こちらの質問を見つけてタグを作る必要があると感じました。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1874/playframework2-2%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

信用度を150超えた場合、自分で追加することができます。

> [権限についてのヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

とりあえず、下記の質問に追加しました。

[Playframework2.2でリクエストのプロトコルを取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1874/playframework2-2%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)